Django: Middleware for JWT Token Encryption and Cookie Setting
I'm working on implementing JWT token encryption in my Django application using rest_framework_simplejwt. I've created a custom middleware TokenEncryptionMiddleware that encrypts access and refresh tokens before setting them as cookies. However, the client-side seems to receive the unencrypted response from TokenObtainPairView.
What am I missing here? Are there any interactions between rest_framework_simplejwt and custom middleware that I need to be aware of to ensure my encryption works as intended?
Here's my middleware code:
"""
Middleware for crypting the JWT tokens before setting them as cookies.
"""

from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class TokenEncryptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Middleware to encrypt the JWT tokens before setting them as cookies.
    """

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        Encrypts the JWT tokens before setting them as cookies.
        """
        if response.status_code == 200 and (
            "access" in response.data and "refresh" in response.data
        ):
            base_key = settings.JWT_KEY.encode()[:32]
            cipher = Fernet(urlsafe_b64encode(base_key))

            encrypted_access_token = cipher.encrypt(
                response.data["access"].encode()
            ).decode()
            encrypted_refresh_token = cipher.encrypt(
                response.data["refresh"].encode()
            ).decode()

            del response.data["access"]
            del response.data["refresh"]

            response.set_cookie(
                "access_token",
                encrypted_access_token,
                httponly=True,
                secure=True,
                samesite="Strict",
            )
            response.set_cookie(
                "refresh_token",
                encrypted_refresh_token,
                httponly=True,
                secure=True,
                samesite="Strict",
            )

        return response

Middleware order
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "middlewares.crypter.TokenEncryptionMiddleware",
]

Expected behavior:
The client should receive cookies named access_token and refresh_token containing the encrypted JWT tokens.

There is a magic method required to create custom middleware in the form of a class.
class TokenEncryptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Middleware to encrypt the JWT tokens before setting them as cookies.
    """
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        
    def __call__(self, request):

        response = self.get_response(request)
        self.process_response(request, response)

        return response

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        Encrypts the JWT tokens before setting them as cookies.
        """
        ...

In Django Middleware, the __call__magic method is called upon request, response.
Your jwt token encryption process is expected to run in the response, so I added it in the __call__magic method.
